# Table cell content(title) moving left after selecting cell

Tags: ios, iphone

[image]

In tableview cell, I have set cell title text alignment as center, It is working fine but after selecting cell, title aligning left. this issue is only in iOS 7.0.

**Edit:**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  BaseListCell *cell = [self.listTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:listCellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
  cell.textLabel.text = _listArray[indexPath.row];
  cell.textLabel.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
        return cell;
}
```

In BaseListCell.m

```
- (instancetype)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {
    self = [super initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        self.textLabel.textColor =[UIColor grayColor];
        self.textLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
        self.textLabel.font = [UIFont mediumFontWithSize:16.f];
        self.textLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
        NSLayoutConstraint *labelHCN = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.textLabel attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.contentView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX multiplier:1.f constant:0];
        [self.contentView addConstraint:labelHCN];
        NSLayoutConstraint *labelVCN = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.textLabel attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.contentView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY multiplier:1.f constant:0];
        [self.contentView addConstraint:labelVCN];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: See the code for cell in tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath. Are you using autolayout?

Comment: Maybe you can provide us some code of didSelectRowAtIndePath or cellForRowAtIndexPath, looks like you are not setting the alignment everytime the cell is being reused

Comment: Yes, using Autolayouts. @user3344236

Comment: There is nothing more with title label in cellForRowAtIndexPath except setting text. And in didSelectRowAtIndePath, I don't have any code related that label.  @亚历山大

Comment: Post your code for cellforRow method

Comment: Did you solve your problem

Comment: can u please exclude self.textLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
        NSLayoutConstraint *labelHCN = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.textLabel attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.contentView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX multiplier:1.f constant:0];
        [self.contentView addConstraint:labelHCN];
 and remaining as below edited questions . can u please recheck my edited answers

Comment: hope you will check my answer soon and will reply me

Answer (score 1):

It is because of autolayout which you have not set properly.
Did you solve your problem. 
**Why do u really need the  following**

```
self.textLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
NSLayoutConstraint *labelHCN = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.textLabel attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.contentView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX multiplier:1.f constant:0];
[self.contentView addConstraint:labelHCN];
NSLayoutConstraint *labelVCN = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.textLabel attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.contentView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY multiplier:1.f constant:0];
[self.contentView addConstraint:labelVCN];
```

I thing you have trouble because of this code. Can u try excluding it

You better declare about the text field as following

**In BaseListCell.m**

```
- (instancetype)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {
    self = [super initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {

    }
    return self;
}



- (void)awakeFromNib {
   self.textLabel.textColor =[UIColor grayColor] 
   self.textLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
   self.textLabel.font = [UIFont mediumFontWithSize:16.f];
  }
```

First enable the  **Use Auto layout** and **Use Size Classes** as below do that first in both table view and table view cell .and tell me your problem

[image]

If you want to place the text vew or label or etc in right of the table view then click on pin of it.[image]

Then select constraint left,right,top and only height. 
[image]

click on add 4 constraints[image]

**you can check this too:**

[iOS - Custom table cell not full width of UITableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30633739/ios-custom-table-cell-not-full-width-of-uitableview/30641193#30641193)

Comment: I am not using Xib. and also same constraints working fine for iOS 8.0.

Comment: Nop, issue is in iOS 7 only.