# Set constraints between 2 buttons in UITableViewCell so that it expands under certain special case

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, autolayout

I have a uitableviewcell that has a certain special case. In this special case, I need to define some constraints between two buttons so the cell isn't too small and the buttons overlap. You can see a picture of the problem here:
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1w9sLgZF0z-uwxzdeP6L_rR14EsaEqjNCghirQxOmFVc/edit?usp=sharing

Basically there are constraints between the like button and  the bottom of the cell, but nothing between the buttons. Note that I only want to add a constraint under a special case, when the text is one or 2 lines; in those cases we have this problem. I'm really not quite sure what the most effective way to do that is, especially getting the number of lines in the UITextview.

I tried this, but it didn't work:

```
 [self addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.likeButton attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual                                                           toItem:self.fromImageView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom multiplier:0.667 constant:0]];
```

Obviously the above code would only be applied in the special case. Thank you for you help.

Comment: your google drive file is not in share mood

Comment: Hi, just changed the url, you should be able now!

Comment: I have up voted urs hope to get it back in my answer too and u can accept it too

Answer (score 1):

its better if you set constraints for universal case if you do so you wont get trouble. cany you check my previous answer

[Table cell content(title) moving left after selecting cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29206375/table-cell-contenttitle-moving-left-after-selecting-cell/29210049#29210049)

You might get some ideas

[image]

For the above image try using following steps

1 For green image select top and left constraints and height and width constraints

2 For fff text select top, left, right constraints and height constraints

3 For gary colour image select left,up,height,width

4 For 0 select left,up,height,width

5  For just Now select right,left,up,height

[image]

I mean to click on that button

Comment: ok, can you specifiy how I would handle this as a universal case? Thank you very much. One universal solution is to specifiy a mimimum cell height but I don't think that's possible.

Comment: Can you check the link above once then ask me questions what you didnt understand. You have to do every things step by step.

Comment: Merely selecting the constraints and then unselecting them doesn't seem to provide a solution. Also xcode 6.3 doesn't have that UI

Comment: I dont mean to select and deselect i just want to show you the constraint . Now can you follow the above instructions please and tell me the results

Comment: i just added a picture to the google doc of what i see when i click on the icon. I am confused about how to proceed.

Comment: First try to study and implement this as a practise http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29206375/table-cell-contenttitle-moving-left-after-selecting-cell/29210049#29210049   and then read above instructions once again and try to solve your questions

Comment: After that click on add 4 constraints .

Comment: you better study http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29206375/table-cell-contenttitle-moving-left-after-selecting-cell/29210049#29210049 this first

Comment: i mean to click on <add 4 constraints> button as shown in image

Comment: ok just did that. now it's added a bunch of white space, see google doc for updated image. Not quite right but getting there

Comment: Basically , the problem is, now the cells dont resize